I fire a mortar vertically upwards, with rifling. When it falls, which direction does it rotate? (Or alternatively: how will it behave?)
I fire a mortar vertically upwards, with rifling. When it falls which direction does it rotate?
Let's ignore whether mortars can actually have rifling and assume it does. So, during the upward trajectory, if one looks vertically upwards, the shell is rotating clockwise. This is the same direction it is rotating if one looks in the direction of travel, i.e. clockwise.
When it reaches apogee, it starts to fall. Let's assume that because of the tail fins, that it gradually rotates so that it eventually is falling downwards, with the bomb end of the shell at the bottom, and the fins at the top.
What direction would the shell now be rotating?

By conservation of angular momentum, clockwise when viewed from below, but rotating anti-clockwise if looking along the direction of travel.

The angular momentum would be conserved along the direction of travel by the aerodynamic action of the tail fins, such that it's still rotating clockwise when looking along the direction of travel, but now rotating anti-clockwise when viewed from below.

the rotation opposes changing direction to point downwards, something like a gyroscope. The rotation gradually slows down, and once nearly stopped, then the shell can finally rotate to point downwards, now with no rotation about its directional axis.

the rotation opposes changing direction to point downwards, something like a gyroscope. The shell starts to tumble as a result, absorbing the rotational momentum. After a while, the momentum has been absorbed by tumbling in the air. The shell then rotates to point in the direction of travel, with no rotation about its directional axis.


(these two possibilities have similar final result, but different intermediate states)
Update: both answers seem good. How to choose 

It would certainly not reverse its spin relative to its own axis, regardless of overall orientation or direction of travel. The gyroscope effect may happen I would guess – it is an very interesting question

I feel like if you shot it directly upwards it should just fall straight down without changing direction, with the warhead still pointing upwards.

Why would it be any different compared to a shallower angle (pick any angle difference you like - no matter how small). To put it differently: if I fired it at a 45° angle, do you believe the shell changes its spin when hitting the peak of its trajectory? What about 45.1°? 45.2°? 45.3°? And so on. Tackle it from the other direction, what about an angle of 135° (i.e. 45° in the other direction)? What about 134.9°? 134.8°? And so on. What's magical about this 90° figure that you're thinking of, and how is it different from 89.9° or 90.1°?

@flater welll, that's a good question, that I was pondering too. So let's pick one of those angles, eg 45 degrees, and think through that. There is no guarantee I feel tah the shell will continue to spin about its directional axis I feel?

@HughPerkins Why? I assume you're not talking about the general loss of spin (angle is irrelevant for that), but rather an inversion of the spin. What force would cause an object to change its spin based on direction of travel, keeping in mind the adage that "in space, there is no up" - which may seem irrelevant due to a mortar being in atmospheric condition but atmosphere doesn't matter here unless you are talking about control surfaces that intentionally change orientation mid-flight, which again is a very different scenario that doesn't seem relevant to your question about the angle

[..] Or, to put it differently, newtonian physics describe that a rigid object in motion will not change their motion unless influenced by an outside force. This also applies to angular motion. What outside force are you imagining that would cause the spin to change? In absence of such a motion, all that remains is that the object spins in the same direction - again ignoring general air friction that can cause a slight loss in angular momentum over time as it seems irrelevant to the question.

@HughPerkins: Also, you can repeat the same +0.1° angle thought experiment when thinking about the projectile's orientation when it is mid-flight. At what orientation does the spin allegedly reverse? Regardless of when you think the spin changes direction (I assume you're thinking of a level projectile pointing sideways), consider the amount of force required to effect an instantaneous inversion of angular momentum, and what kind of havoc that would wreak on the rigid body of the mortar shell.

@Flater Generally speaking, an object can only spin stably about one of the two principal axes with the largest and smallest moments of inertia. For a shell, which has rotational symmetry around its directional axes, it can spin stably either around its directional axis, or around an axis perpendicular to that. If it was to keep spinning at its initial spin, in world axes, after changing the direction of travel, such that the directional axis has now changed, it would no longer be rotating around one of its principal axes. So it would wobble, or precess, or some such.

@HughPerkins Sure, but keep in mind that mortar shells have fins specifically to create drag on the back end of the shell, which effectively acts as a stabilizer that works against that precession. The fins may briefly stop working if you end up having bled most of your angular momentum at the height of your perfectly vertical shot, but that requires those two events to align - this also brings us back to the same "having lost angular momentum" point which seems irrelevant for a question that asks which direction the shell will spin, not if it will spin.

@flater I think the comments are becoming long. Please could you put your thoughts on how the shell will behave when it falls, into an answer, and we can comment there? Please feel free to assume that the shell is angled at epsilon degrees from the vertical, when it starts falling.

I think riffling and fins don't go in the same mortar or the same question. If a shell with straight fins is rotating, aerodynamic drag will stop rotation an the problem becomes one of a non spinning shell.

Yeah, fair point...

As it falls, the tail fins exert a torque.  Without rotation, this would rotate the shell $180^o$.
Since the shell is rotating, this is much like supporting a gyroscope by its axis and trying to rotate it $180^o$. The gyroscope twists sideways. If you support gyroscope on a stand by its axis, it precesses. The same thing happens if you hang it from above.

Thanks! In the absence of air resistance, if one applies a torque to a gyroscope would it precess forever? In our case, we do have air resistance. So the spin along the directional axis will gradually reduce, and then the shell would stop precessing? Or is there some way that the shell could rotate to point in the direction of movement, without losing all of the spin around the directional axis?

Without air the tail fins don’t do much good.

The question here, once the projectile starts falling, becomes a balance between the gyroscopic force trying to keep the projectile pointing up, and the drag of the fins trying to make the projectile point in the direction of travel (down, in this case). As the projectile falls faster and faster, the fins start gaining on that balance. For extreme gyroscopic action, you could maybe have a projectile that keeps pointing up until it lands; but I highly doubt that mortars reach anywhere near that level of angular momentum. Regardless, the spin directly (relative to mortar body) won't change.

Tl;dr: the mortar either goes into chaotic tumbling, or settles into pointing downwards, with or without spin.
Aeronautics and aerodynamics of falling objects is complicated. At least initially, it is possible for the falling mortar-with-fins ("mortar") to tumble chaotically instead of merely reorienting itself in the streamline attitude. Note that once it does reorient itself, the tail fins exert no torque.
To simplify (grossly, by ignoring vortex shedding, resonances, turbulence, geometric imperfections etc), lets model the spinning mortar as a spinning right circular cone. We start time at the apogee. It points to the sky.
Ideally, it should just fall without changing its orientation. But fluid motion isn't ideal. The drag on the edge of the blunt bottom would have have slight perturbations. The unbalanced drag would produce a net-torque. The cone would begin to tilt (still pointing towards the sky and spinning).
The tilted bottom presents a new attack surface, thus a new drag profile. Say the maximum drag is applied at the most risen part of the bottom. The resulting torque would cause the cone to tilt in a different direction. Repeat.

fig. 1: illustration showing a cone precessing as it reorients into a streamline attitude. Red, green and blue dashed lines show +x, +y and the whole z axes in the lab frame. Time progresses left to right, top to bottom. Origin is at the center of mass of the cone. Not a simulation.
What the preceding paragraph describes is merely the onset of precession. Notice how it tacitly assumed that the drag torque is small enough so as not to cause outright tumbling and overshoot.
At this point, we have enough of a mental picture to see what's going on - the drag force is reorienting the cone, so it eventually points downwards towards the ground, all the while (first increasingly, then decreasingly) precessing.
Notice how for the smooth cone, the drag never touched the initial spin (in magnitude) since the torque it generates never aligns with the spin. This isn't the case for our "mortar". Imagine the cone in the midst of its reorientaion: currently, it's pointing towards the horizon (and precessing like a lighthouse's lightbeam). Say it grew tail fins. The tail fins rotating into the wind experience more drag than their counterparts. This torque is (anti-)aligned with the original spin. If the tail fins get enough time in the wind, the'll 'eat up' all of the original spin. The cone goes on to pointing downwards, just without precession.
However, the presence of tail fins make a rapid reorientation more likely than a slower one, so they may not get enough time after all. Once streamlined, they become passive as far as the original spin is concerned.
So there are three possible outcomes; the mortar -

 tumbles chaotically to the ground
maintains its helicity (spins as when launched when looking in the direction of motion [here, clockwise]) but points downwards as it falls
 looses spin altogether and just points downwards as it falls.

I suspect when you do real world experimentation, you would get all three of these outcomes depending on the mortar's shape and initial conditions.
Now (quickly) the cases you proposed:

By conservation of angular momentum, ...

It isn't, so no.

The angular momentum would be conserved along the direction of travel by the aerodynamic action of the tail fins, such that it's still rotating clockwise when looking along the direction of travel, but now rotating anti-clockwise when viewed from below.

I argued above that the aerodynamic action of the tail fins can eat up the spin, not merely reorient the mortar, depending on how much time the mortar spends in the supporting orientation. So yea and nay.

the rotation opposes changing direction to point downwards, something like a gyroscope. The rotation gradually slows down, and once nearly stopped, then the shell can finally rotate to point downwards,

If the angular momentum is large enough to overcome all aerodynamic forces, then there's no point in having an aerodynamic mortar shape. That shape is designed to orient itself along the wind. Imagine launching such a mortar in a parabolic trajectory! So technically yes but practically, expect the drag to dominate. Also the slow down of the rotation is primarily because of the tail fins (precession alone doesn't change the magnitude of spin), though if you waited long enough it could die from surface drag alone.

the rotation opposes changing direction to point downwards, something like a gyroscope. The shell starts to tumble as a result, absorbing the rotational momentum. After a while, the momentum has been absorbed by tumbling in the air. The shell then rotates to point in the direction of travel, with no rotation about its directional axis.

Tumbling need not necessarily stop the spin, it may also impart it. In addition, the mortar may tumble too transiently, only to stabilize pointing downwards (with same/opposite/no spin). Once chaotic motion starts - predictions become hard. So again, yes and no.

If it has fins, and if they're not perfectly parallel to the axis, they would create torque to either reinforce or counteract the spin from the rifling.

@WGroleau Indeed. I assumed they are, as the simplest, most common sense scenario. Without a CAD of the mortar, such effects are hard to reason about.

Even perfectly parallel fins would have air resistance to counteract the spin.  I would suspect an engineer designing a projectile with fins would provide a slight angle to maintain spin, if spin is desired.  Rifling implies spin is desired.  And spin might be desired so that gyroscopic effect resists tumbling (for aiming accuracy).  But I'm a software engineer (retired), not a ballistics engineer, so I could be way off base.
